# append multiple files into one, skip the first row and sort

Tags: python, bash, sorting, pandas, awk

I have a folder containing monthly files of hourly values. Each of the 12 files has a one line header. Each file has a line for every hour, for every station, in that month. See below:

```
Hours   stn stn_id  sen_id  Elevation   Latitude    Longitude   cnt avg_hrly
2010-01-01 00:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-01-01 01:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    59  0.0
...
2010-01-31 22:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-01-31 23:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
...
2010-01-01 00:00:00 Arbutus 79  159 57  48.47133255 -123.30664062   60  0.0
2010-01-01 01:00:00 Arbutus 79  159 57  48.47133255 -123.30664062   60  0.0
...
```

PROBLEM IS, come March there is an hour from the preceding month in each file from the Daylight Savings shift, like so:

```
Hours   stn stn_id  sen_id  Elevation   Latitude    Longitude   cnt avg_hrly
2010-05-31 23:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-06-01 00:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    56  0.0
...
```

The appending part is quite easy, though I am sure there is a better way, especially considering I need to do 2 things as well:

1. Skip the header of each file being appended. Nevermind the first instance, I can just paste one at the top after.
2. Sort the resulting appended file based on column 2 to get the station names together, then on column 1 to sort each station by hours.

**DESIRED OUTCOME:**

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-01-01 01:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    59  0.0
...
2010-01-31 22:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-01-31 23:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-02-01 00:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-02-01 01:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-02-01 02:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
...
2010-05-31 20:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.6
2010-05-31 21:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-05-31 22:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-05-31 23:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-06-01 00:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    56  0.0
2010-06-01 01:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-06-01 02:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-06-01 03:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  0.0
2010-06-01 04:00:00 Alberni 108 217 26  49.24596024 -124.8041687    60  10.4
```

I am wondering if this is going to require some awk and shell combined, with pipes?

Here is some pseudo, pseudo code, simply to convey the approach:

> for file in *.csv; do awk NR>1 {print} | sort -k2,1n | >>
>   year_appended.csv ; done

Maybe this is a challenge better conquered using Python, perhaps with the Pandas library for working with a time series. If so, I am guessing a group by statement, or two.

Comment: So skipping the header is trivial, what are you wanting to do with the files that have an hour from previous month, skip these or keep them? Are these duplicate values when you combine them all?

Comment: keep them and that is where the sort function comes in. I suppose I should provide an ideal outcome dataset, standby....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sort for `-s` (stable sort):

```
awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv | sort -sk 2,2 | sort -sk 3,3
```

Here `awk 'FNR > 1'` filters for lines that are not the first line of a file<sup>1</sup>, and `sort -sk m,n` sorts stably by fields `m` through `n`. To sort not only by hour but also by date, use

```
awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv | sort -sk 1,2 | sort -sk 3,3
```

Note that this depends on the date and time formatting. As luck would have it, lexicographical comparison of the date and time stamps works with the given representation, so more complex parsing is unnecessary.

<sup>1</sup>An explicit `{ print }` action is not necessary; the default action (printing) is performed when the condition is true.

**Addendum:** If you have GNU awk and the fields in the file are strictly tab-separated, you could also use

```
gawk -F '\t' 'FNR > 1 { data[$2,$1] = $0 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; for(d in data) print data[d] }' *.csv
```

Here `-F '\t'` tells gawk to split lines into fields along tabs, and the code works as follows:

```
FNR > 1 {                                  # for all lines that are not the
                                           # first of a file:
  data[$2,$1] = $0                         # remember them by fields 2 and 1
}
END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"   # GNU-specific: Require sorted
                                           # traversal of arrays.

  for(d in data) {                         # Then print the lines in that
    print data[d]                          # sorted order.
  }
}
```

Comment: date and time formatting is how you see it. I will try your solution tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: just about worked; I have a sorted year, in date order, but not by hours. Can you explain more about what the 1,2; 2,2; and 3,3 are doing in the sort -sk? Also, I think our "luck" ran out...the "date time" field is one, separated by a _space_. The rest of the file is tab-delimited. Does this require to parse the first field on the _space_ so that we can also sort on the hour (the second field after we've parsed on that _space_)?

Comment: `sort` splits (by default) along whitespace, so field 1 will be the date, field 2 the timestamp regardless of whether the fields are separated by tabs or spaces. `sort -sk 1,2` sorts by fields 1 and 2, which is the date and time. Afterwards, sorting stably by field 3 will yield data that is major-sorted by field 3 and minor-sorted by fields 1 and 2.

Comment: This works great, and I have not tried the GNU awk method, but appreciate the explanation. Thanks for the excellent solution and for correcting my edits in the placement of {print} :)

Answer (score 3):

Some pseudo code, you don't need to skip the rows here as the [concatenation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) will align the columns for you, also it will be much faster to just make a list of dfs and then concatenate them all together rather than appending one df at a time:

```
# assuming you have a list of the files you want to load, probably via glob

df_list=[]
for file in file_list:
    df_list.apend(pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['Hours']))

merged = pd.concat(df_list)
# sort the data
merged = merged.sort(['stn', 'Hours'])
```

Comment: I am really glad you provided a python answer, as I am learning both shell (etc.) and python at the moment so that provides a lot of insight for me into the nuances between the two languages. I learnt a lot from your post, thanks.